# Exclude \n when reading input from file

Tags: python, file-io, newline

I am attempting to return user location data while scrapping twitter. I am having trouble with the regex, specifically, I wish to *exclude* "\n" from the output.

Current regex:

```
data = open("user_locations.txt", "r")
valid_ex = re.compile(r'([A-Z][a-z]+), ([A-Za-z]+[^\n])')
```

user_locations.txt:

```
California, USA
You are your own ExclusiveLogo
Around The World
Galatasaray
★DM 4 PROMO / CONTENT REMOVAL★
Glasgow, Scotland
United States
Berlin, Germany
Global
```

Expected output:

```
['California, USA', 'Glasgow, Scotland', 'Berlin, Germany']
```

Actual output:

```
['California, USA\n', 'Glasgow, Scotland\n', 'Berlin, Germany\n']
```

An alternate reason for the discrepancy between expected vs actual output, may be the way in which I am using search() in printing the list. That is:

```
for line in data:
    result = valid_ex.search(line)
    if result:
        locations_list.append(line)
    print(locations_list)
```

Thank you, any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: "\n" isn't a part of a regex match unless you do a multiline search with "DOTALL". The \n wasn't in the regex match, but it is in the original line and that's what you saved. You could do `line.strip()`.

Comment: You don't need a regex, and this is just a generic thing when reading input from file.

Comment: Curious which other answers you saw that weren't a solution? SO is full of variants of this question going back a decade. If anything there are too many duplicates and we need to close some in favor of others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you find a match, you call `locations_list.append(line)`.  This appends the entire line (including the newline character), not just what was matched.

Here are a couple options to get your desired result:

***Option 1***

Change `locations_list.append(line)` to `locations_list.append(line.strip())`

***Option 2***

Grab the result of the desired match instead:

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    print(re.findall(r'[A-Z][a-z]+, [A-Za-z]+', f.read()))
```

Output:

```
['California, USA', 'Glasgow, Scotland', 'Berlin, Germany']
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [`str.strip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) to remove the trailing newlines?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be replace all contiguous whitespace characters with a single space.

```
text = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', text)
```